# React Native Android Released APK throws error t[n] is not a function

Tags: react-native

React Native Android Released APK throws error t[n] is not a function. Here is the actual error:

> com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: t[n] is not a function. (In 'tn', 't[n]' is 
>       undefined), stack:
>
> ```
> <unknown>@340:168
> value@49:1280
> value@28:3311
> <unknown>@28:822
> value@28:2565
> value@28:794
> value@-1
> ```

Comment: you should see the js log. the natives can not find the relative info.

Comment: Improved formatting